# How to add a "." after a String under Conditions in R

Tags: regex, r, nlp, conditional-statements

```
Data <- c("My name is Ernst.","I love chicken","Hello, my name is Stan!","Who?","I Love    you!","Winner")
```

The Function should add a "." if at the end of the Sentence is none of those signs [.?!] to end the sentence.

I was trying do build a function in R with help of Regex but i had some issues to only look at the End of the String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below `gsub` function would add a dot at the end of the sentence only if the sentence is not ended with a `.` or `?` or `!` symbols.

```
> Data <- c("My name is Ernst.","I love chicken","Hello, my name is Stan!","Who?","I Love    you!","Winner")
> gsub("^(?!.*[.?!]$)(.*)$", "\\1.", Data, perl=TRUE)
[1] "My name is Ernst."       "I love chicken."        
[3] "Hello, my name is Stan!" "Who?"                   
[5] "I Love    you!"          "Winner."
```

In regex, lookaheads are used for condition checking purposes. The negative lookahead `(?!.*[.?!]$)` would checks for the presence of `.` or `?` or `!` at the line end. If it's present at the last, then it skips the sentence and the replacement would never happen on that corresponding line. The replacement would occur only if there is no `.` or `?` or `!` symbols at the last.

**OR**

Through negative lookbehind and positive lookahead,

```
> Data <- c("My name is Ernst.","I love chicken","Hello, my name is Stan!","Who?","I Love    you!","Winner")
> sub("(?<![!?.])(?=$)", ".", Data, perl=TRUE)
[1] "My name is Ernst."       "I love chicken."        
[3] "Hello, my name is Stan!" "Who?"                   
[5] "I Love    you!"          "Winner."
```

Answer (score 2):

using `stringi`

```
library(stringi) 
stri_replace_all_regex(Data, "(?<![^!?.])\\b$", ".")
#[1] "My name is Ernst."       "I love chicken."        
#[3] "Hello, my name is Stan!" "Who?"                   
#[5] "I Love    you!"          "Winner."
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possible approaches:

**1)** If the last character is not dot, ? or ! then replace it with that character followed by dot:

```
sub("([^.!?])$", "\\1.", Data)
```

For the data in the question we get:

```
[1] "My name is Ernst."       "I love chicken."        
[3] "Hello, my name is Stan!" "Who?"                   
[5] "I Love    you!"          "Winner."
```

**2)** A gsubfn solution is even simpler.  It replaces the empty () with a dot if the last character is not a dot, ! or ? .

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("[^.!?]()$", ".", Data)
```

**3)** This one uses `grepl`.   If dot, ! or ? is the last character then append the empty string and otherwise append dot.

```
paste0(Data, ifelse(grepl("[.!?]$", Data), "", "."))
```

**4)** This one does not use regular expressions at all.  It picks off the last character and if its one of dot, ! or ? it appends the empty string and otherwise appends dot:

```
paste0(Data, ifelse(substring(Data, nchar(Data)) %in% c(".", "!", "?"), "", "."))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution.

```
x <- c('My name is Ernst.', 'I love chicken', 
       'Hello, my name is Stan!', 'Who?', 'I Love    you!', 'Winner')
r <- sub('[^?!.]\\K$', '.', x, perl=T)
## [1] "My name is Ernst."       "I love chicken."        
## [3] "Hello, my name is Stan!" "Who?"                   
## [5] "I Love    you!"          "Winner."
```